# unable to login to docker via command line

Tags: docker, authentication, command-line, docker-registry, colima

I was switching from Colima to docker desktop. I am done uninstalling Colima and have installed docker desktop
However now when I am trying to pull any image(including public images)or trying to login
I am getting this error

`Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unexpected EOF`

Although I am able to login to my docker desktop.

I have already tried

1. changing context to `docker context use default`
2. setting up auths directly in docker/config file :

```
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
      "auth": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "email": "x.y@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}
```

3. Modified DNS server setting to 8.8.8.8
4. also verified that there are no special character in my docker password.
5. I don't have any proxy in my system
6. also tried removing credsStore from docker/config file.

```
System configuration: 
OS : Ventura 13.2.1

Server: Docker Desktop 4.17.0 (99724)
Engine:
  Version:          20.10.23
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following format for "auths", with auth as the base64 encoded 'username:password' string. Obtain it as `echo -n 'username:password' | base64`.

```
{
   "auths" : {
     "https://index.docker.io/v1/" : {
       "auth": "XXXX"
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried the above solution but it didn't work in my case